# I did my research, but still cant put text above my image: NEW CODER

Tags: html, image, css

Here is my CSS:

```
.info {
    color: black;
    padding: 100px 15%;
}

.info img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter:alpha (opacity=40); /* For IE8*/
}

.info p {  
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.info h3 {  
    font-size: 36px;  
    margin: 0;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="info" id="aboutus">
    <h3>About Us</h3>
    <img src="image/pink.jpg">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to display the text above the image with a drop shadow on the text, and i'm stuck.

Comment: Do you mean stacked above vertically or overlaying the image?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

#### About Us

text

http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg

#### HTML

```
<div class="info" id="aboutus">
    <h3>About Us</h3>
    <p>text</p>
    <img src="image/pink.jpg" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.info img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter:alpha (opacity=40); /* For IE8*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your text and images in separate DIVs.

```
<div class="info" id="aboutus">
    <h3>About Us</h3>
    </div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l5lTl.png">
        <p>text</p>
```